# Tool tip on table data

Tags: php, html-table, tooltip

I am developing a Gant chart using PHP and purely based on table architecture. What I need is that when user mouse over the data

```
echo "<td colspan=$duration align=center
bgcolor=$color>$description\r\n";
```

to show a tool tip with some related information. Any guidance please.

Below is part of my codes.

```
foreach ($this->activities as $activity) {
$start = $activity['start'];
$end = $activity['end'];
$description = $activity['description'];
$color = $activity['color'];
$before = $start;
$duration = $end - $start + 1;
$after = $this->end - $end;
echo "<tr>\r\n";
if ($before > 0) {
echo "<td colspan=$before>&nbsp;\r\n";
}
echo "<td colspan=$duration align=center
bgcolor=$color>$description\r\n";
if ($after > 0) {
echo "<td colspan=$after>&nbsp;\r\n";
}
}
echo "</table>\r\n";
}
}
```

Comment: What related information? Do you want some kind of box to appear when you hover over the table row?

Comment: Yes is possible some kind of box because on click and pop-up I feel is not suitable. Any best suggestion please ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are plenty of tooltip plugins available for download.

Comment: Also, this seems more like a HTML/CSS/JavaScript related question.

Comment: I was trying pop-up. I feel is annoying where user need to click and then only it appears. Can you suggest which plugin to use so I can explore it

Comment: A quick Google search and I found this: http://istockphp.com/jquery/creating-popup-div-with-jquery/. Good luck :)

Comment: This one is on click which I dont want. I prefer on mouser over the tool tip to appear on every of my td which have information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Twitter Bootstrap (getbootstrap.com) or qTip2 (qtip2.com) - they have very good examples how it works. Basically what you need to do is simple:
1. Get the data you want the tooltip to contain.
2. Print it as part of the object that you want to use it on ( `<button title="Some Tooltip Here">Some Button Text</button>` - Example usage with both of the plugins I gave you above )
3. Add JS code that defines that the object you want has tooltip on it.
Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('[title!=""]').qTip();
}
```

This code will enable the tooltip for all of the object that have title attribute ( Code from qTip2's official documentation )

Comment: Can I get the data dynamically when I mouse over to get it via ajax and then show it accordingly ?

Comment: Yes, check qTip2's documentation ( http://qtip2.com/plugins#ajax ) there you can see a pretty good example of Ajax usage ) Some advices I can give you... print data to the object again in different attributes and get them via the JS/JQ code.

Comment: What you mean by print the data? Will also work on my td elements ? Should not be a problem right?

Comment: Yes! '<td title="<?php echo $the_tooltip; ?>" ajax_attribute1="<?php echo $the_tooltip_ajax_attr_one; ?>" ....>' This is an example (bad one I know), but echo() is used to print data to the HTML or w/e document there is.

Comment: Ok let me download and do some test and later will get back here. I guess I will need some time for this and thank you for exposing me this tool and which version should I download cause they wrote there this ajax is depreceated.

Comment: Just download jQuery latest and qTip2 latest.

Comment: I am following the guide <!-- jQuery FIRST i.e. before qTip (and all other scripts too usually) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include either the minifed or production version, NOT both!! -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>

<!-- Optional: imagesLoaded script to better support images inside your tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.imagesloaded.pkg.min.js"></script> but I dont find jquery.imagesloaded.pkg.min.js it instead this imagesloaded.pkg.min

Comment: I have tried a simple thing like this $the_tooltip= "TEST";
    echo "<td title=".$the_tooltip." colspan=$duration align=center
bgcolor=$color>$description\r\n";$(document).ready(function () {
     $('[title!=""]').qtip();
  } but nothing seems to come out ?

Comment: Now I am getting this error Object #<Object> has no method 'qTip'

Comment: You are doing most of the attributes wrong, and qTip2 must be called from the head, after the jQuery file is called!

Comment: Yes I have done its works now. But I am stuck how to do the ajax one? What should I write ? I dont get you with your suggestion here ajax_attribute1="<?php echo $the_tooltip_ajax_attr_one; ?> ?

Comment: You still stuck? Sorry.. I wasn't online for a lot of time!